# Search and return multiple results in one cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, concatenation, lookup, worksheet-function

I'm a bit of an Excel novice. I have searched but couldn't find an answer. Based on input from Columns A and B:

**Column A**

```
Gonnella Italian Soft Rolls  
Gonnella Sub Buns  
Healthy Life 100% Whole Wheat Soft Style Sandwich Buns  
Healthy Life Wheat Hot Dog Buns  
King's Hawaiian Bread Round Original Hawaiian Sweet  
King's Hawaiian Original Hawaiian Sweet Hamburger Buns
```

**Column B**

```
Gonnella
Healthy Life
King's Hawaiian
Wheat
Italian
Sandwich Buns
Hamburger Buns
Hot Dog Buns
```

I am looking for output in Column C like so:

```
Gonnella|Italian
Gonnella
Healthy Life|Wheat|Sandwich Buns
Healthy Life|Wheat|Hot Dog Buns
etc...
```

I want to search for keywords in Column A using the keywords that are in Column B and have the results in Column C (as shown above) separated by `|` between each keyword.

I know I can use `=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH(B$1:B$10,A1),B$1:B$10),"")` but it only gives me one result.

Is it possible to get multiple results into one cell using the search and lookup function (or any other function)?

Comment: Thank you pnuts! For some reason, when I add the rest of the formula as you mentioned it came out using the same word, example: "Italian|Italian" instead of "Gonnella|Italian" I had to create a couple columns for the keywords (one column would be the brand name the other would be type, etc.) for that to work but it works!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for example with your formula and `&"|"&` and then another formula (without = at the start of that) - all in the one cell.

If the formulae either side of the pipe are the same then so should the results be, or Excel would be showing inconsistency.

The `&` is a short way of [concatenating](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/concatenate-function-HP010062562.aspx) and with a pipe between the two formulae the results will always be strings.

The separator is more commonly a comma and hence will usually include a space: `&", "&`